# How to only observe the last character in Firebase

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm new to firebase, read most of the IOS documentation, but could not find an answer. I'm trying to build an app where many different users can add a letter to the end of a string. I am worried that updating this constantly will be a massive drain on resources and would like a way to reduce this.

```
let ref = Database.database().reference()
ref.observe(DataEventType.value) { (snapshot) in
    if !snapshot.exists() { return }
    let book = snapshot.childSnapshot(forPath: "book").value
    self.text.text = book as! String
}
```

From what I've read, it sounds like using .value will look through the entire child snapshot. I have no idea if Firebase realtime database is just not optimal for a thing like this, or if I am just missing an obvious solution to this problem.

My end goal is to have some form of download of the entire string available on the device, and the only thing having to be observed is the last character of the string when it is updated.

Comment: The question is a bit unclear. You can easily observe a string stored in Firebase and be notified of any changes. So for example, if the stored string is 'abc' and userA adds a 'd' to it so it's now 'abcd' all of the users will be notified of that change. Then userB adds an 'e' to it so the string is now 'abcde' all of the users will receive that notification as well. Can you clarify what you're trying to do?

Comment: Also, *it sounds like using .value will look through* - you have two .value in your question;`DataEventType.value` and `.childSnapshot(forPath: "book").value`. Neither will 'look' through anything. They both return all data at the specified ref - the first one accesses the actual server ref, whereas the second accesses the data contained in the snapshot returned from the first ref.

Answer (score 2):

It's not possible to query or observe anything smaller than an entire child node. Even if that node contains a single child value which is a string, you're going to be reading that entire string every time.

Consider instead storing each character as a different child, paired with a timestamp, and adjust your query to only examine the child with the newest timestamp.  To rebuild the entire string, just read all the children in and concatenate all the characters in timestamp order.